# How to fit a convex quadrilateral inside another short of cutting them out and playing with them?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I have two convex quadrilaterals (ABCD and WXYZ).  Their sides and their interior angles are known.  I also know that WXYZ fits perfectly inside ABCD with each corner point touching a different side.

Is there any way to figure out analytically where the touches occur?
For example, if I knew AX or angle BXY, everything else would be obvious because it is all triangles.  But how to find out where X is on line AB?

... Of course, I can always draw the things on different pieces of paper, cut WXYZ out, fit it by hand and then measure the result.  But that isn't terribly precise.  (!!)

[I've shown WXYZ inside ABCD in the linked image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iACkd.png)

Comment: *How* do you know wxyz fits perfectly inside abcd? There are at most 4 ways to do this.  (four possible lines for the first point).  Start be assuming A goes on line WX.  Label one of the resulting angles theta and figure the remaining 7 angles in terms of theta.  Use law of cosines and law of sines to calculate what the new lengths must be and if they have a solution.  Try this four times until you get something that works.

Comment: So in that image. Let the measure of angle AXW = theta. sin A/WX = sin theta/WA = sin(180-theta-A)/AX,  sin B/XY = sin(180-theta-X)/BY = sin(theta+ X - B)/BX, etc.  Use these to figure out the lengths and angles.

Answer (score 1):

Assume a solution.

Let a = m angle A; b= m angle B; and so on.

Let $\theta = $ m angle AXW.

By law of sins:

$\sin a/WX = \sin \theta/AW = \sin(180 - \theta - a)/AX$

$\sin b/XY = \sin(180 - \theta - x)/BY = \sin(\theta + x - b)/XB$

$\sin c/YZ = \sin(180-y - \theta - x + b)/ZC = \sin(y + \theta + x - b - c)/YC$

and

$\sin d/WZ = \sin (\theta + a - w)/DZ = \sin (180 - d - \theta - a +w)/DW$.

(And we can also note: $180 - d -\theta - a + w = 180 - z - y - \theta -x + b + c$)

Using these was can solve AW,AX,BY,XB,ZC,YC,DZ, DW.

Comment: Mind you, the fact that 180−d−θ−a+w=180−z−y−θ−x+b+c doesn't help because it just resolves into a+b+c+d = w+x+y+z.

Comment: Thank you!  Mind you, I'm baffled as to solving for theta and AW, etc with just the above. But if I add the fact that AB, BC, CD and DA are known, then with (1)DW+AW=DA  and (2)sin(d)/ WZ = sin(180−d−θ−a+w)/DW and (3)sin(a)/WX = sinθ/AW, then, substituting for DW and AW in (1) I get WZ*sin(180−d−θ−a+w)/sin(d) + WX*sinθ/sin(a) = DA.  And the only unknown in that is θ.  Yay!  .... But that isn't an equation I know how to solve.... maybe there's an easier equation still to be found!

Comment: Well, sin a/wx = sin theta/aw and sin d/wz = sin(180−d−θ−a+w)/dw.  And aw + wd = ad is known.  That should make theta solvable.  ad = aw + wd = sin theta*wz/sin a + sin(180 - d - thteta - a + w)*wz/sin d.  So ad/wz = sin theta/sin a + sin(180 - d - theta - a + 2)/sin d.  It's a single trig equation with only theta unknown.

Comment: Yes, that's sorted, thank you very much!  I don't actually know how to solve for theta when the equation looks like 0 = sin(θ +c) + sin(θ) + g, but I can always plug different values in and find one that works. :)  Thanks again; I was 100% stuck without your help!